# Why does VB.Net throw an error when running an Access update query while it runs properly in Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am running an Access update query in VB.Net.

`dbCustSpec_ADO.Execute("table_upt")`

Ir runs fine except for the following "Update to" statement

`[table].[field1] & [table].[field2]`

The following is working properly

`[table].[field1]`

So does the following

`[table].[field2]`

It is only when I concatenate both fields when VB.Net throws an error:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.'`

Btw: The concatenation works properly when calling the query in Access.

My question is:
How can I concatenate both fields in order to make it run while calling it from VB.net

Comment: sql always uses a + sign for concatenation. (this applies to both sql server, JET sql). So in vb.net code you can use + or & --- but in sql expressions, ALWAYS use + sign, and & is not supported.

Comment: I just updated the query in Access to `[table].[field1] + [table].[field2]` but it is still throwing an error

Comment: On the other hand, isn't this line `dbCustSpec_ADO.Execute("table_upt")` not just executing the Access query? why does it give an error while it does not when executing directly in Access?

Comment: see my answer below. running a sql update (saved) query in access is different then running a sql statement. I provide both examples below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not clear, are you using the .net oleDB provider here?

Or are you creating a instance of the Access database engine?

You better off to use oleDB such as this:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

And then your code to update can look like this:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTAce)
        Dim strSQL As String = "UPDATE tblHotels SET FullName = FirstName + ', ' + LastName"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

And if you wanted to ran a "existing" update query in Access?
They are considered store procedures. Say we have upate query saved in Access called

```
qryFirstLast
```

Then the above code to run that query would be:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTAce)
        Dim strSQL As String = "qryFirstLast"
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Note how we set the command type = StoredProcedure.